# How can I submit one HTML form to multiple php files?

Tags: php, html

**I have an HTML form that I need to submit to a php file that adds it to a database, as well as to an existing php file that adds it to an online CSV file.**

Any ideas?

Comment: you cant, you have to submit to one file, and in that include the other files\code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a new php file, like this:

```
<?php

  include('form_handler_1.php');
  include('form_handler_2.php');

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the $_POST or $_GET array to call the other file.

For example after your mysql take the $_POST and submit them with $_GET to the next file.

file 1:

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$address = $_POST['address'];
## put here your mysql query and connect
## end query

##submit the values as variables to the other script

$url = "http://www.mysite.com/seconfile.php?name=".$name."&address=".$address;
file_get_contents ($url);
```

second file:

```
$name = $_GET['name'];
```

Curl would also fit or fopen or file.

You can do that endlessly and shorten the coding with using a foreach loop through the array creating the urls.

coded but not tested

Comment: Can I also use POST to send it to the second file?

Comment: POST requires curl instead of file_get_contents. secure the get params or use a strange filename than u should be save though :)

Answer (score 0):

You could send it to your database php file, and then use curl to send the request to the second php file.

[See this link for instructions on how to use curl](http://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php) :)

Comment: seems convoluted you should only use curl for external requests, not internal.

Comment: I also need to complete and submit an online form using php later on, think curl will come in handy..

Comment: @Dagon true, but couldn't think of another way really.

Comment: @Andre Make sure you mark the answer as answered to help out other people in the future :)